# Is Request.Headers["Header-Name"] in ASP.NET case-sensitive?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers

Is `Request.Headers["Header-Name"]` in ASP.NET case-sensitive? And if it is, how should I get a certain header (e.g. "X-requested-with") if I don't know for sure what case the client will send it in?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

no they are case-insensitive as per [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

> 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as 
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
>   ***are case-insensitive***. The field value MAY be preceded by any amount
>   of LWS, though a single SP is preferred. Header fields can be
>   extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at
>   least one SP or HT. Applications ought to follow "common form", where 
>   one is known or indicated, when generating HTTP constructs, since
>   there might exist some implementations that fail to accept anything

Answer (score 6):

`Request.Headers` is case-insensitive.

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/55153):

> From [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1", §4.2, "Message Headers":
>
> > Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

Comment: From the remarks on [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) (which is the implementation type of [`HttpRequest.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx)): `The hash code provider dispenses hash codes for keys in the NameValueCollection. The default hash code provider is the CaseInsensitiveHashCodeProvider.`

Comment: "Headers" is a NameValueCollection and the key is not case sensitive. "QueryString" and "Form" are also NVC's and as such are not case sensitive either unless the comparer is changed

Answer (score 0):

I never used ASP.NET but RFC HTTP/1.1 defines that [message-headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) field-name are case insensitive.

If ASP.NET follow HTTP Specification, Request.Header["Header-Name"] will return the same value that Request.Header["header-name"].

Comment: 2021: Tested on netcore 3 : Headers are case insensitive.