# ASP.NET Request.Form case-sensitivity

Tags: asp.net, case-sensitive, namevaluecollection, request.form

I have some C# code that retrieves the value of Request.Form["KeyName"], however, the code that is submitting the request is passing keyName=value. This works in our dev/stage environment, but not in production.

This post [Is Request.Headers["Header-Name"] in ASP.NET case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616964/is-request-headersheader-name-in-asp-net-case-sensitive) suggests that the expected behavior would be for this to work b/c the NameValueCollection uses a case-insensitive comparer. Is there a configuration setting that might be different between the servers? Both are running ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: ASP.NET actually uses an internal class `HttpValueCollection` however that explicitly sets it as `OrdinalIgnoreCase` making it case-insensitive. I suspect something else might be up. Can you dump your `Request.Form.AllKeys` property?

Comment: Not easily in production - making code updates is not a trivial process.

Comment: You could attach a debugger or run a copy of the website on a development machine, surely?

Comment: Yes, but as the problem only expresses itself in production, I'm not sure what I would be looking for.

Comment: Set a breakpoint where you're doing the key-lookup in Request.Form and see if the specified key exists in the collection, or if the keys that are in there are misspelled or something else.

Comment: Well, if I do this on a dev machine, I know the specified key exists b/c it works. Further testing is showing it's not the case-sensitivity -- production is behaving differently when the request is issued from Fiddler rather than from the browser.