# Angular 10 / .Net 4.8 Request Headers Changed to be Camel Case

Tags: c#, .net, angular

So I my app chanced authentication Management, previously all headers were added in a load balancer.
The new method works and in order to not have to rewrite code we are using an angular interceptor to inject the headers in the HTTP request there

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ICAM_RIOT", "RIOT");

```
 private void hasResponseHeaderCollection(string headerName, string Value)
    {
      if (!HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AllKeys.Any(k => string.Equals(k, headerName)))
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(headerName, Value);
      }
    }
    private string GetHeaderStringValue(string headerName)
    {
      return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[headerName] ?? "";
    }
```

Please see the photos,

All the headers are UPPER CASE

WHEN received on the .Net api side they are camel Case

For instance     ICAM_MAIL becomes Icam_mail

I even tried on the .net side to add a rseponse header all caps and it comes back camel case as well

[Client Side Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS3v0.png)

[response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsnae.png)

Comment: Http headers are [not case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive/5259004), so why does it matter?

Comment: I second the comment by @gunr2171 . You should process both on the client and on the server side ignoring casing.

Comment: .Net net side is not fiding the header then I pass in a string looking for it for example it cannot find a head for "ICAM_MAIL" but can find "Icam_mail"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP headers are [case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive/5259004). Whenever you lookup a header value by Key it needs to be a case insensitive match.

`Request.Headers[headerName]` [handles this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616964/is-request-headersheader-name-in-asp-net-case-sensitive), but `Response.Headers.AllKeys.Any(...)` will not because you're doing your own string comparison, which defaults to case sensitive matching. Use [the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-6.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-string-system-stringcomparison)) of `string.Equals` that allows for a StringComparison object and use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: You are correct, I guess before the load balancer always injected them in uppercase, and Angular does something different, that one overload did the trick