# Setting application wide HTTP headers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, mvvm, angularjs

Is there a way to set the `$httpProvider` headers outside of `angular.module('myApp', []).config()`?

I'm getting an Auth-Token from the server after I login the user, and I need to add it as a HTTP Header to all following requests.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'token';
```

It seems `headers()` normalizes the key names.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by normalizes the key names?

Comment: When getting the headers using the headers() method, the key "Auth-Token" gets lowercased and becomes "auth-token". Which is confusing.

Comment: @lucassp may be this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Answer (score 67):

You can use default headers for angular **1.0.x**:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authentication'] = 'authentication';
```

or request interceptor for angular **1.1.x+**:

```
myapp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {

      // use this to destroying other existing headers
      config.headers = {'Authentication':'authentication'}

      // use this to prevent destroying other existing headers
      // config.headers['Authorization'] = 'authentication';

      return config;
    }
  };
});

myapp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

Since factories/services are singletons, this works as long as you do not need to dynamically change your 'authentication' value after the service has been instantiated.

Comment: A bit confused. How do I integrate this into my app? Do I need to list as a dependency and then use `$httpProvider` instead of `$http`?

Comment: Inject $httpProvider into your config method that hangs off of your app module. Providers are a way of configuring services before they get injected by Angular into your controllers etc.

Comment: @AakilFernandes It's only a configuration. You can inject $http directly.

Comment: This is very strange. When i use $http.defaults.headers.common i get an error 405 (Method Not Allowed). I am unsure if the issue here is webapp2 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above responses of @Guria and @Panga

```
config.headers['X-Access-Token'] = $window.sessionStorage.token;
```

One can use x-access-token in header as JWT(jsonwebtoken).
I store JWT in the session storage when a user authenticate first time.