# How can I get my ngResource to accept custom headers?

Tags: angularjs

My code in coffeescript :

```
  resource = $resource GlobalService.apiRoot + "stuffs", {},
    get:
      method: "GET"
      headers:
        "Accept": "application/stuffs;version=3"
        "Authorization": 'Token token="' + $.cookie('token') + '"'
```

My code in javascript :

```
var resource;

resource = $resource(GlobalService.apiRoot + "stuffs", {}, {
  get: {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/stuffs;version=3",
      "Authorization": 'Token token="' + $.cookie('token') + '"'
    }
  }
});
```

Then when I do..

```
resource.get ->
```

It doesn't send out those specified headers, and effectually fails the CORS authorization.

Any recommendations?

Comment: IIRC, there was a fix put in for this several months ago. Have a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/965

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: 1.0.3  ... I'm trying to figure out where that commit was even pushed ;)

Comment: Try 1.0.4 ... it's the latest stable version as of right now.

Comment: Actually, looking through the actual source for current releases of Angular (1.0.4 and 1.1.2), it looks like you need to use the unstable 1.1.* version to get that headers setting: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-resource.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting application wide HTTP headers in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183025/setting-application-wide-http-headers-in-angularjs)

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Mtsf-YdwwWo/P_Ui4t_DiXkJ "I'm able to set headers and even custom headers. You need to set it under the default for $http, $resource has the $http dependence."

Comment: @MarkRajcok I tried setting it with the `$http.defaults.headers.common` and as well within the `$resource` call and it does not pass those header parameters as expected. This is still an unresolved non-functional piece of development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that headers setting is only available in the latest "unstable" release of Angular. If you use this, be sure to upgrade both angular.js and angular.resource.js to 1.1.2 (current unstable release).

- http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.js
- http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular-resource.js

Comment: Ha, I accepted my answer too soon. This actually doesn't work.. Headers are not set.

Comment: I just tried it myself, and it is definitely setting the headers. Set a breakpiont in $httpBackend and check the headers that are passed to that method. You should see your headers in there. If you're not seeing the headers, it might be something on your server's end.

Comment: Also, set up Fiddler and watch what's being sent out.

Comment: FYI: httpBackend is around line 9230 in 1.1.2/angular.js