# ngResource Dynamic Header

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, ngresource

I'm trying to make a request to an API service that has a dynamic 'authorization' header.

```
  var domain = "http://www.externalapi.com",
    actions = {
      'login': {
        method: 'POST'
      },
      'objects': {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': Request.getAuthHeader()
        }
      }
    };

  var requests = $resource(domain, {}, actions);

  requests.objects();
```

`Request` is a service I've written that has a method that builds the auth header based on the api requirements, the has it returns is correct.

When looking at the request to `domain`, however, I see not 'Authorization' header...

I've also tried passing in a static string, still no header.

Comment: what is your AngularJS version? look [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821482/how-can-i-get-my-ngresource-to-accept-custom-headers).

Comment: Angular v1.0.8, ngResource v1.0.8

Comment: As instructed by that solution I updated to 1.1.2, however I'm still not seeing any custom headers being passed with my requests. I then updated to 1.2.0rc1... Still no headers.

Comment: Use this $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = Request.getAuthHeader(); as the basic authorization header. And overwrite it in the method you defined.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was my versions.

After updating Angular to 1.2.0rc1 I left my ngResource module at 1.0.8.

After updating both to 1.2.0rc1 (I assume 1.1.2 would work as well) I was able to assign headers from the actions object of $resource.