# Trouble changing Content-Type for POST requests with ngResource (1.0.6 and 1.1.4)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

First, I know this question has been asked several times. I have tried many posted solutions and nothing is working for me..

Here are a few other places this was asked:

- [How to specify headers parameter for custom Angular $resource action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791667/how-to-specify-headers-parameter-for-custom-angular-resource-action)
- [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)
- [Setting application wide HTTP headers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183025/setting-application-wide-http-headers-in-angularjs)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Mtsf-YdwwWo/P_Ui4t_DiXkJ

The attempts:

```
var app = angular.module('theApp', ['app.services']);


app
  .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    // Try (1): This doesn't work
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
    // Try (2): This doesn't work either
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
  }])


angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
  // Resource for Drupal system/connect.post API (via services.module)
  .factory('SystemConnect', function($resource, $http) {
    // Try (3): There's no way this should work. But what the hell let's try!
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';

    return $resource('api/system/connect.json', {}, {
      post: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: { },
        isArray: true,
        // Try (4): This doesn't work either
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }
      }
    });
  });


function SomeCtrl($scope, SystemConnect) {
  // FAIL, this results in "406 Not Acceptable: Unsupported content type application/xml"
  $scope.user = SystemConnect.post();
}
app.controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl);
```

It sounds like many people have solved this before. Could someone kindly let me know the right way to do this?

PS: Weirdly, when running this code in Firefox, Angular uses 'Content-Type: text/plain' for the POST!?

Comment: I remember reading you have to include content in a post for it to accept your header changes. Just a wild guess thought...

Comment: That was it Mike! `$scope.user = SystemConnect.post({});` works, totally weird. Put it in an answer.

Comment: Easiest answer ever, glad to help

Comment: Which of the above tries (1-4) did actually work in combination with the .post({})?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading you have to include content in a post for it to accept your header changes.

```
$scope.user = SystemConnect.post({});
```