# Identify file header using php

Tags: php

I want to find the file type hosted in external server.I tried get_headers() function but it returns an array of headers i need the content type only.The array is in different order according to the file so it can't be identified using position of array element.Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the `format` parameter to `1`, it'll make an associative array of the headers:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$content_type = $headers['Content-Type'];
```

See [the documentation of `get_headers`](http://gr2.php.net/get_headers) for more information.

Comment: Why is **my** before variables?

Comment: @Rolice: Hah, my bad. I code too much perl, is why. Fixed. :)

Comment: Yep, I thought it is Perl... but I doubted if it is something new I missed around PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: [`array_change_key_case`](http://php.net/array_change_key_case) is advisable, because `get_headers()` returns the plain results. [Headers are *case-insensitive*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive) however, and while almost never an issue (Apache normalizes some), it's not guaranteed that it's labeled exactly `Content-Type`. `CONTENT-TYPE` and `content-type` or `cONTent-tYpe` are also permitted.