# getting json in flask from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, flask

I need some help with getting json data in flask from jquery ajax.

Below client side javascript which gets called whenever some button is clicked.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function change_status(item, status) {
          var statusObj={"desc":item, "status":status};
          $.ajax({
                    url:"/robot/api/"+item,
                    type: "PUT",
                    contentType:"applicaton/json",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(statusObj)
          });
    }
</script>
```

on server side(flask), I have below code to catch json data.

```
@app.route('/robot/api/<item>', methods = ['PUT'])
def update_item(item):

print "content_type: ", request.content_type

print "request.json: ", request.json

if not request.json:
    print "bad json format"
    abort(400)
else
    """
    do something like update data
    """
```

### In PC, when clicking button in the browser which calls javascript function, flask server is printing below message:

```
"content_type:  applicaton/json; charset=UTF-8

request.json:  None

bad json format

192.168.1.241 - - [12/Feb/2014 15:06:16] "PUT /robot/api/3g HTTP/1.1" 400 -"
```

It shows request.content_type is json but when actually printed it says None.

I did packet capture to see data from PC with wireshark and I see below:

### From PC to Flask Server:

```
PUT /robot/api/3g HTTP/1.1

Host: "my flask server ip address"

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0

Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: applicaton/json; charset=UTF-8

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Referer: "my flask server ip address"

Content-Length: 28

Connection: keep-alive

{"desc":"3g","status":"off"}
```

But Flask server returns "HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST"

Comment: Have you tried using `data: statusObj`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you are missing the "i" in "application/json". Change your jQuery call to `contentType:"application/json"` (rather than `contentType:"applicaton/json"`) and everything should work just fine.

Flask only loads the payload in the request body as JSON [if the content type is `application/json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json) - anything else and you have to load the JSON yourself, using [`request.get_json(force=True)`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

Comment: Thanks Sean, You're right. I'll so stupid. wasted 2 days of my evening time for simple mistake...

Comment: This works! But `Content-Type` is widely spreaded (which is not recognized by Flask), what is the standard?

Comment: @FrozenFlame - [the standard is application/json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/135978)

Comment: @SeanVieira Thanks. But I meant, `Content-Type` or `contentType` o r `ContentType`. camelCase or Dash-separated? Case sensitive or not?

Comment: HTTP headers [are not case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/135978) but they must be dash-separated. Other languages and frameworks will change how the keys are handled to make it more convenient to access *from the language in question* - in jQuery's case, being JavaScript they use the camelCase variant because it doesn't need to be quoted when used as a key.