# How to pass multiple headers and override content type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following function which I can not override:

```
  getHtml:function(aURL,aPostData,aHeaders,aMethod){
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var tmp=this;
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
      tmp.onStateChange();
    };
    if(aPostData||aPostData==""){
      this.xhr.open(aMethod?aMethod:"POST", aURL, true);
      this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }else this.xhr.open(aMethod?aMethod:"GET", aURL, true);
    if(aHeaders){
      for(var t in aHeaders){
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader(t,aHeaders[t]);
      }
    }
    try{
      this.xhr.send(aPostData);
    }catch(e){
      this.doNext("");
    }
  }
```

How should I pass several headers (`aHeaders`) to this function? If I pass `Content-Type` as the header, will it override default value (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) there?

I would like to pass two headers:

1. `x-myheader-value`: `zzz1111bbb`
2. `content-type`: `application/javascript`

Comment: What circumstances to you have where it makes sense to POST JavaScript to the server and get HTML back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your function expects an object like:

```
var headers = {
    "x-myheader-value": "zzz1111bbb", 
    "Content-Type": "application/javascript"
};
...
getHtml( ... , headers, ...);
```

However if you set multiple times the same header, the expected behaviour is that the value would be concatenated, not replaced... See [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/#dfn-setrequestheader) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()). So in your case, if you pass the Content-Type header when also passing a non empty `aPostData` object, you will end with the wrong header value.

Comment: By the way, header names are [case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Is there any trick I can use to override (=replace) the content type value, when that `getHtml` function is used? As you mentioned, it concatenates the value, which is wrong. Let's say, can I somehow pass payload data in the header instead of usage `aPostData`?

Comment: The cleanest way would be for that function not to add a content-type header if there is one in the argument aHeader. But you mentioned that you cannot change that function...