# how to keep key case sensitive in request header using golang?

Tags: go, header, request, case-sensitive

I am recently using golang library "net/http",while add some header info to request, I found that the header keys are changing, e.g

```
request, _ := &http.NewRequest("GET", fakeurl, nil)
request.Header.Add("MyKey", "MyValue")
request.Header.Add("MYKEY2", "MyNewValue")
request.Header.Add("DONT-CHANGE-ME","No")
```

however, when I fetch the http message package, I found the header key changed like this:

```
Mykey: MyValue
Mykey2: MyNewValue
Dont-Change-Me:  No
```

I using golang 1.3, then how to keep key case sensitive or keep its origin looking?
thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive - "Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive."

Answer (score 21):

The [http.Header](http://godoc.org/net/http#Header) [Add](http://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Add) and [Set](http://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Set) methods canonicalize the header name when adding values to the header map. You can sneak around the canonicalization by adding values using map operations:

```
request.Header["MyKey"] = []string{"MyValue"}
request.Header["MYKEY2"] = []string{"MyNewValue"}
request.Header["DONT-CHANGE-ME"] = []string{"No"}
```

As long as you use canonical names for headers known to the transport, this should work.

Comment: It works to me now, thx. yes, "[]string" is useful, it's same as the "request.Add(key, value)" for one key with multiple values.

Comment: Cool. Does anyone knows why this "canonicalization" is done?