# Using an authorization header with Fetch in React Native

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to use `fetch` in React Native to grab information from the Product Hunt API. I've obtained the proper Access Token and have saved it to State, but don't seem to be able to pass it along within the Authorization header for a GET request.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var Products = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      clientToken: false,
      loaded: false
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function () {
    fetch(api.token.link, api.token.object)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
        this.setState({
          clientToken: responseData.access_token,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getPosts();
      })
      .done();
  },
  getPosts: function() {
    var obj = {
      link: 'https://api.producthunt.com/v1/posts',
      object: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.clientToken,
          'Host': 'api.producthunt.com'
        }
      }
    }
    fetch(api.posts.link, obj)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
      })
      .done();
  },
```

The expectation I have for my code is the following:

1. First, I will `fetch` an access token with data from my imported API module
2. After that, I will set the `clientToken` property of `this.state` to equal the access token received.
3. Then, I will run `getPosts` which should return a response containing an array of current posts from Product Hunt.

I am able to verify that the access token is being received and that `this.state` is receiving it as its `clientToken` property. I am also able to verify that `getPosts` is being run.

The error I'm receiving is the following:

> {"error":"unauthorized_oauth", "error_description":"Please supply a valid access token. Refer to our api documentation about how to authorize an api request. Please also make sure you require the correct scopes. Eg \"private public\" for to access private endpoints."}

I've been working off the assumption that I'm somehow not passing along the access token properly in my authorization header, but don't seem to be able to figure out exactly why.

Comment: As noted in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004), headers are intended to be **lowercase** (some servers respect this, others do not.)  I only share because I was bitten by it not knowing myself (and wasted time trying to debug the issue.)  It is unfortunate that so many projects, examples, and articles do not seem to respect this.

Comment: @t.j. Header names are not case sensitive, and that's exactly what the accepted + top answer says on the question you linked.

Comment: 5.5 years later and I was setting a fetch header just like the OP:
`'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myJWT,`

Turns out myJWT was getting wrapped in double quotes!
`Authorization: Bearer "yadda.yadda.yadda"`

After many attempts at a solution, I filtered the double quotes on my back-end.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It turns out I was using the `fetch` method incorrectly.

`fetch` accepts two parameters: an endpoint to the API, and an optional object which can contain body and headers.

I was wrapping the intended object within a second object, which did not get me any desired result.

Here's how it looks on a high level:

```js
    fetch('API_ENDPOINT', options)  
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
       })
      .then(function(resJson) {
        return resJson;
       })
```

I structured my options object as follows:

```js
    var options = {  
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Origin': '',
        'Host': 'api.producthunt.com'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'client_id': '(API KEY)',
        'client_secret': '(API SECRET)',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      })
    }
```

Comment: could you perhaps provide the now working code? I'm trying to use fetch with an authorization header and I don't think my auth code is being passed as a header, because I'm getting a `401` response.

Comment: Done, hope it's helpful

Comment: Oh i've been on your personal site with that example! That's how I modeled mine the first time. I figured out my issue though, it was just that my url was wrong. It required a `/` at the end that I was missing...

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  Worth noting that while the fetch documentation points out that fetch doesn't handle cookies, you can manually add cookies to the header with this code as well.  Just save the uid and key and do something like: var obj = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cookie': 'uid='+uid+'; key='+key
            });

Comment: @RichardKho could you please check my post here. Was not able to get an answer until now.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75235933/flask-jwt-extended-exceptions-noauthorizationerror-missing-authorization-header

Answer (score 309):

Example fetch with authorization header:

```
fetch('URL_GOES_HERE', { 
    method: 'post', 
    headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password'), 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }), 
    body: 'A=1&B=2'
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me.  The `'Authorization'` header silently fails to attach per firebug.  I've even tried including `credentials: 'include'` in the optional object.

Comment: @RonRoyston are you looking at the OPTIONS call? if the API endpoint doesn't have CORS enabled (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * if accessing from a different domain), then it might fail at the OPTIONS call.

Comment: api endpoint does not have CORS enabled, so that's probably why it didn't work for me.  Thanks.  I ended up installing 'cors everywhere' add-on for firefox and it worked.

Comment: Re the issue @RonRoyston is seeing, **you need to import the btoa library**, which is not native to node.  (It's a port of a browser lib.)  Otherwise auth header creation silently fails.  We were experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Shouldn't the Authorization header format for Token based authentication look like `Authorization: Token token=123123123`? [reference](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/02/03/token-based-authentication-rails/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch per docs, need to wrap headers with `new Headers()`

Comment: @RonRoyston I used your 'cors everywhere' addon suggestion and was able to send the authorization header and get response. My question is: my application will be accessed by the customer and I do not want to ask them to download the addon in order to use my app. How can I solve my issue, without having to download the addon.

Comment: you will have to proxy the request from a secure server environment, such as a Node.js/Express.js server.

Comment: @Marklar `Authorization: "Basic {}"` would mean `Authorization: "Token 123123123"`

Comment: Note: If "grant_type=client_credentials" is part of your request, the "Basic" token is likely not supposed to be accessible to the public. Client credentials are used for machine-to-machine communication. More info here: https://auth0.com/docs/applications/confidential-and-public-applications

Comment: VSCode says `The signature '(data: string): string' of 'btoa' is deprecated.` with TypeScript

Comment: @kaushalpranav apparently you need to use `window.atob` instead https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566#issuecomment-905059122

Comment: could you please check my post here. Was not able to get an answer until now.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75235933/flask-jwt-extended-exceptions-noauthorizationerror-missing-authorization-header

Answer (score 34):

The following code snippet should work if you're using the bearer token :

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, // notice the Bearer before your token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(yourNewData)
})
```

Answer (score 16):

I had this identical problem, I was using django-rest-knox for authentication tokens. It turns out that nothing was wrong with my fetch method which looked like this:

```
...
    let headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    if (token) {
      headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    }
    return fetch("/api/instruments/", {headers,})
      .then(res => {
...
```

I was running apache.

What solved this problem for me was changing `WSGIPassAuthorization` to `'On'` in `wsgi.conf`.

I had a Django app deployed on AWS EC2, and I used Elastic Beanstalk to manage my application, so in the `django.config`, I did this:

```
container_commands:
  01wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Comment: `django.config` its in a project or in apache config?

Answer (score -7):

```
completed = (id) => {
    var details = {
        'id': id,

    };

    var formBody = [];
    for (var property in details) {
        var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");

    fetch(markcompleted, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: formBody
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson, 'res JSON');
            if (responseJson.status == "success") {
                console.log(this.state);
                alert("your todolist is completed!!");
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```