# react-native fetch does not pass authorization header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authorization, httprequest, fetch

I'm using `react-native` 0.51.0. I have dozens of pages(components) where I make `GET`, `POST` requests. All works perfectly, except one of them. It seems, `Authorization` header does not pass during the call.

My request options are like

```
requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
    }
};
```

I get "`Token not provided`" error message when I run the code, but I try same token, exactly same request options through `postman`and it works perfectly.

I surfed through lots of questions, issues and tried lots of suggested solutions like adding

```
access-control-allow-origin
credentials: 'same-origin
credentials: 'include'
```

But nothing changed.. I'm sure my token is true and not expired. Lots of suggestions are related with CORS thing. But what I do not understand, if true then why all other `fetch` methods work ? I call all http requests to the same server.

Comment: guys. finally bug fixed. 
It was nothing related with front-end. I was doing everything right. developers on back-end side changed something with `url` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
fetch(API_URL, { 
  method: 'get', 
  headers: new Headers({requestOptions})
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native)

Hope that helps.