# How to perform JWT API request on Express.js server? (edX API)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt, request-promise

This is probably a super-easy answer for most folks, but I'm new to back-end. I'm using Express.js to implement my server, and I need to retrieve courses from the edX API. Below is the sample request they have on their docs:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: JWT {access token}" https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs/
```

and I can't seem to find a starting point on how to translate this to Express.js implementations. I was able to perform similar requests to another API using 'request-promise'), but this is the first that requires a JWT Auth...

Docs here: http://course-catalog-api-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/course_catalog/catalog.html#get-a-list-of-all-course-catalogs

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was super similar to the above, but with a different setup (using the **request-promise** library):

```
request.get('https://api.edx.org/catalog/v1/catalogs/', {
 "url":APIURL,
 "headers":{
    "Authorization": "JWT {access token}",
    "User-Agent": "client"
  }
});
```

Source: [Using an authorization header with Fetch in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

## How can we perform a request with `HTTP AUTH` ?

From this Github Issue : [**Bearer Token**](https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/111)

> Please have a look at the [Request documentation](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication). Request-Promise works
>   the same.

#### With the `request` module:

```
request.get('https://some.server.com/',{"auth":{"bearer":"theToken"}})
```

#### With the `request-promise` module:

We know it works as `request` so we could build the options like this :

```
var options = {
 "url":APIURL,
 "headers":{"User-Agent":"client"},
 "auth":{"bearer":ACCESSTOKEN}
}
```

---

So now you can even create a route in your express app, that performs the query using a client-side token :

```
app.get("/query-with-token/:accessToken",(req,res)=>{
 var accessToken = req.params.accessToken
 if(accessToken){
   console.log(accessToken);
   RequestAPI((error, apiResponse)=>{ //this would be a custom function of yours
     if(!error){res.send(apiResponse)}
     else{res.send("ERROR: "+error)}
   })
 }else{res.send("no token supplied")}
})
```

(this approach is not recommended for security reasons)