# Battle.net API returns 401 Error using OAuth Token

Tags: node.js, api, express, passport.js, battlenet-api

**I'm using Nodejs with express on the Battle.net API to generate an Oauth Token.** https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth

Generating the token itself works, as it returns me the token. But when I use the code to make a request to their API, for example:

https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Malfurion/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=HEREISMYTOKEN

I get a 401 Unauthorized Error Response, debug log:

```
{ url:
      'https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Malfurion/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=HEREISMYTOKEN',
     status: 401,
     statusText: 'Unauthorized',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] } }
```

I'm trying to fetch the members of a guild via fetch().

**I already tried:**

- Creating a new Application (with new Client Secret and ID)
- setting every possible callback url in the battle.net settings:

  https://localhost/
  http://localhost/
  https://localhost:443/
  http://localhost:443/
  https://localhost/auth/bnet/callback
  http://localhost/auth/bnet/callback
  https://localhost:443/auth/bnet/callback
  http://localhost:443/auth/bnet/callback
- creating a token manually by "trying out the api" (https://develop.battle.net/documentation/api-reference/world-of-warcraft-community-api), where you put in your Client ID and Secret and then get a temporary Token. THAT ONE works, also in my application.

**You can compare response of those two urls (just use your browser):**

First (Generated in my application): https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Blackmoore/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=EU7XD8E4K9IAJKBGJSP3MDBLAVCIU2BYXS

Second (Generated trying out the API on battle.net website where you fill out clientid and secret to test out the api): https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Blackmoore/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=US23su4g0hAeS5w3EUCkKA9MJPgJ8k8bzV

**CODE**

server.js, simple express app

```
var BNET_ID = "MYID";
var BNET_SECRET = "MYSECRET";

...

// Use the BnetStrategy within Passport.
passport.use(
  new BnetStrategy(
    { clientID: BNET_ID,
      clientSecret: BNET_SECRET,
      scope: "wow.profile sc2.profile",
      callbackURL: "https://localhost/",
      region: "eu" },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    })
);
// bnet auth routes
app.get('/auth/bnet', passport.authenticate('bnet'));

app.get('/auth/bnet/callback',
    passport.authenticate('bnet', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res){
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

controller.js

```
...

      const res = await fetch(`https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/${servers[iterator]}/The new Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=${thetoken}`).then((res) => {
        res.json();
        // for debugging, shows 401 Error
        console.log(res);
      });

...
```

**I actually expect a response such as this, because it works using a temporary Token:**

```
status: 200 OK

body: {
  "lastModified": 1546676373000,
  "name": "The new Dimension",
  "realm": "Blackmoore",
  "battlegroup": "Glutsturm / Emberstorm",
  "level": 25,
  "side": 0,
  "achievementPoints": 1005,
  "members": 
(......)
}
```

## I managed to resolve the issue!

Very, very hacky but I managed to resolve the issue by hacking the oauth callback middleware like this:
set my used API token to the req.user.token.

```
app.get('/auth/bnet/callback',
    passport.authenticate('bnet', { failureRedirect: '/?error' }),
    function(req, res) {
      req.session.bnettoken = req.user.token;

      res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

I suspect that "code" or "token" is also used in my SessionStorage (express-session) to store the current session in my database. So I just hack the user.token out of the request and use that. Phew.. Hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I can see that you need to pass the token into the `Authorization` header with value of : `Bearer HEREISMYTOKEN`.

More info on Authorization Header and Headers here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

Example on how to use it can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native/50865025#50865025)

Comment: so where do I set the authorization header? I thought I just get a token that I then put into my fetch url.

Comment: because using my own generated token via oauth2, im getting the same error as using any key, such as "PEPEE", response from that is url:
      'https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Blackmoore/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=PEPEE',
     status: 401,
     statusText: 'Unauthorized',

Comment: When you make an HTTP Request, there are several headers that you can attach to the request, In this case it's `Authorization`.

Comment: so do I need to add something to my fetch?

Comment: I've added links on how you can add headers to your fetch. Please have a look

Comment: Well the Api works when you append your API token to get GET request url. I cant see how adding a header would work.

Comment: try using https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Blackmoore/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=EU7XD8E4K9IAJKBGJSP3MDBLAVCIU2BYXS

Comment: and then https://eu.api.blizzard.com/wow/guild/Blackmoore/The%20new%20Dimension?fields=members&locale=de_DE&access_token=US23su4g0hAeS5w3EUCkKA9MJPgJ8k8bzV - just use your browser, as you can see it works, so maybe I got something in my Battlenet strategy wrong?

Comment: I think I resolved it. Thanks for the help anyway! :)