# How to pass authorization token in header for GET method using XMLHttpRequest in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to pass the authorization token through a header in the GET method. But I am getting an unauthorized error.

I have already tried this code "[Using an authorization header with Fetch in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native)" not working for me and also with `XMLHttpRequest()`

But the API works fine in postman, Java(core) and Android.

Do we have any special implementation in react-native to pass headers? 
Could anyone can help me with this?

My code: Changed the server name.

```
getData() {
    var data = null;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;


    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "https://xyz-test-server.server.com/api/v3/users/details/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic cC5qYWltdXJ1Z2FuLm1jYUBnbWFpbC5jb206MTIzNDU2");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1");
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "d8ae56bf-1926-44e4-9e94-23223234,93a110a2-ee8e-42d5-9f7b-45645ddsfg45");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

    xhr.send(data);
}
```

**Fetch method:**

```
async _getProtectedQuote() {
  fetch('https://xyz-test-server.server.com/api/v3/users/details/', { 
    method: 'GET', 
    headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Basic cC5qYWltdXJ1Z2FuLm1jYUBnbWFpbC5jb206MTIzNDU2', 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }), 
  }).then(responseJson => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
    console.log(responseJson);

  });
}
```

Comment: Show me the code you tried.

Comment: Please post the code you tried using both the Fetch API as well as XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I have add my code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try interceptor for pass token into header.

Put all requests in one service file name `service.js` then `import Interceptor from '../interceptor';`

make one `interceptor.js` file and write below code in file.

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {

if (config.method !== 'OPTIONS') {

        config.headers.Authorization = 'Basic cC5qYWltdXJ1Z2FuLm1jYUBnbWFpbC5jb206MTIzNDU2';

    }

    return config;

}, function (error) {

// Do something with request error 

console.log('how are you error: ', error);

return promise.reject(error);

});

axios.interceptors.response.use(

(response) => {

    return response

},

async (error) => {

    // const originalRequest = error.config

    console.log("error in interceptors=============>", error);

    if (error.response.status === 500) {

        alert(error.response.data.message);

        NavigationService.navigate('Login');

    } else {

        return Promise.reject(error)

        }
    }
)

export default axios;
```

When api calls header will pass through by interceptor automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch Api converts all headers into lower-case. We need to do case-insensitive server side parsing.

Comment: could you please explain