# Make a HTTP POST request with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http

Do you how to make a POST request from React of the following:

`http --auth name:password POST http://localhost:5000/api/tokens`

My current attempt to make a request with React is as follow:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'name',
        password: 'password'
    })
};
fetch('/api/tokens', requestOptions).then(res => res.json());
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780539/3930247

Comment: Thank for the page, but I don't see how I can link this to my issue

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password'),` you can try this part.

Comment: Thank you, that works. But when the authentification is wrong, the browser gives me a sign in dialog box, how do I get rid of that? I've tried to handle this in .then() or .catch(), but it seems like the dialog box is appearing before .then() is activated.

Comment: You can do it with the catch block. Sounds like your app already has some fallback exception handling.

Comment: As I explained: the dialog appear before the catch block is being executed. Here's my code:

`fetch('/api/tokens', requestOptions).then(res => res.status).catch((err) => {alert(err.status); return err.status;});`

The catch block isn't being taken into account.