# Slack's apps.connections.open returns "invalid_auth" when I send the token via request body

Tags: fetch, authorization, slack-api, bearer-token

I'm trying to call Slack's API from browser, so I ran following in Chrome's dev console, and got an error:

```js
await (await fetch("https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({'token': 'xapp-1-MYTOKEN'})
    })).json()
→ {ok: false, error: 'invalid_auth'}
```

I thought that providing token via request body should be fine, for the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.connections.open) says so:

> Tokens should be passed as an HTTP Authorization header or alternatively, as a POST parameter.

Am I missing something?

---

I tried equivalent (I think) cURL commands and the same result.

```sh
$ curl -s --data-urlencode token@TOKEN https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open | jq
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "invalid_auth"
}
```

I made sure that my token was correct; the API call succeeds when I send the token via Authorization header:

```sh
$ curl -s -X POST -H Authorization:\ Bearer\ $(<TOKEN) https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open | jq .ok
true
```

Note that Authorization header cannot used when using Fetch API, for CORS limitation (the access-control-allow-headers header doesn't include "Authorization").

---

I understand that generally it's not a good idea to call Slack API from browser, to keep token secret.

Comment: It looks like you have to use a different method now for submitting the token: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2020-11-no-more-tokens-in-querystrings-for-newly-created-apps

Comment: @Pikamander2 Thanks for the link but I don't think so. I believe that what is deprecated is sending tokens in query string, i.e. https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open?token=TOKEN; sending tokens as a POST request is still valid.

Comment: Can you try this with your fetch method ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native

Comment: @SuyashGaur Sorry I don't get what you point out. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted to Slack support, and got an answer: their documentation is currently incorrect and tokens should always be passed as an HTTP Authorization header when you use this API.