# How can I prevent Heroku from CamelCasing response headers?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm using heroku to serve a simple nodejs express service. The problem I am running into is that the consumer of this service (I do not have access to the consumer code) expects headers returned by the service to be all in lower case. Heroku seems to be converting the headers into camel case automatically, and after much Googling I can seem to find a way to disable this behavior.

For example:

If I set a header like "**access-control-allow-credentials**", it will be sent as "**Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**", which the consumer does not recognize.

I know these headers should be case insensitive, but because I cannot modify the consumer, I'm hoping there is a way to pass them through without modifying the case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,

Royce

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Comment: I think you mean Capitalizing, not camelCasing