# xwiki REST ajax call error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, xwiki

Hi all i have an istance of xwiki on my localhost, for a test purpose i wanted to test the RESTful api by writing some simple jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var username = "Admin";
var password ="admin";  

function make_base_auth(user, password) 
  {

    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    alert(hash);
    return "Basic " + hash;

  }

var url = "http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/query?q=object:XWiki.XWikiUsers";
var returnData = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    url: url,
     headers: {"authorization":  make_base_auth(username, password), "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },

    error: function(request, status, error) 
    {   
        alert(error) 
    },
    success: function(data) 
    {
       alert("success");

    }

       });    
</script>
```

the error i get is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/query?q=object:XWiki.XWikiUsers.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

but trying with postman i get the correct result...i'm missing something?
thanks

Comment: if you send authentication information it is no longer a "simple" request and you need to configure XWiki (in the `web.xml`) to allow these requests ... do you really need the auth info? (Probably yes, if the wiki is not public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default configuration XWiki does not allow CORS; you need to enable it in the `web.xml`

To allow sending authentication data with the `authentication` header,  edit the file web.xml and add a new filter among the section with the filters:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Set CORS headers very lenitent</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>value</param-name>
    <param-value>authorization</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Now you need to activate the filter; further down among the `filter-mapping`s add your own:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Set CORS headers very lenitent</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

(and yes, if you do not like the filter name, use a different name, just use the same name in both places.)

As you figured out in the comments, allowing several HTTP headers works like:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Set CORS headers very lenitent</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>value</param-name>
    <param-value>authorization, content-type</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

(in this case allowing both the `authorization` header and a "non-standard" `Content-Type` header) (side note: headers are case-nsensitive: [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258977))

Also you need to allow CORS in general for REST-request; for this search for:

```
<!-- We set the CORS policy globally for webjars.
   ... longer comment ....
  -->
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Set CORS policy for fonts</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>resourceReferenceHandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/webjars/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

edit the filter-mapping and add a line `<servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>` to activate this filter for the rest servlet, too:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Set CORS policy for fonts</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>resourceReferenceHandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/webjars/*</url-pattern>
  [...]
```

After a restart of the servlet container the AJAX request should now work.

Comment: Great but how can i modify the xml to allow also:
Access-Control-Allow-Methods?
This because trying a put method it raised that error

Comment: Probably the same way, i.e. add yet another `<filter>` with  `<filter-class>org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter</filter-class>` and where `<param-name>name</param-name>` is `<param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Methods</param-value>`. not sure about the   `<param-name>value</param-name>` however ...

Comment: ... probably `<param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE</param-value>` - more CORS stuff e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  (but sure there is a better ref?)

Comment: my doubt was about the filter class, thanks i'll try

Comment: now i get:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
when i perform a POST method

Comment: ok now it seems to do the authorization and the put (without specifying the contentType)...but...because i should specify the type of data i pass i set : contentType:"application/xml", and i get Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: i'm lucky that xwiki accept the default application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so i can send it..but i'm curious to know how to add this contentType option to web.xml

Comment: web.xml documentation e,g, at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html  and CORS tutorial: see my last comment

Comment: mmm adding <init-param>
    <param-name>value2</param-name>
    <param-value>contentType</param-value>
  </init-param>
to <filter-name>Set CORS headers very lenitent</filter-name>
still give me errors regarding contenType...

Comment: solved this way  <param-value>authorization, Content-Type</param-value> thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify web.xml file for enabling cors (I am using jetty server). 
I added the below mentioned filter.

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
         <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
         <param-value>origin, content-type, accept, authorization</param-value>
       </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Then you need to Download and add jetty servlet jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.4.22.v20191022/jetty-servlets-9.4.22.v20191022.jar)

Put this jar inside the lib folder, then restart your server and the cors is enabled for jetty server.