# How to make superagent request headers case sensitive?

Tags: php, node.js, superagent

I'm writing a superagent client for a PHP application.

I'm struggling to get one of the first examples to work:

```
.set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
```

appears to send headers `x-api-key: foobar` (and `user-agent:  node-superagent/1.7.2`) to server, so I lose the case. Is it normal (i.e. I should make serverside case-insensitive when working with superagent), or am I missing something?

A quick dive into superagent source code shows that there is intentional `.toLowerCase` call, but it just doesn't seem right, does it?

Comment: Although headers are meant to be case-insensitive, it's interesting that same code on Mac is sending lowercase headers, but on Windows they are unchanged. (both using superagent 1.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH boy!

I totally missed this: [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive)

The answer is - http headers should not be case sensitive, so sending lowercase is valid, and server-side must take care of it.

It is however easy to fall to `getallheaders()` which returns an assoc array which is case sensitive.