# View Express JS response headers?

Tags: javascript, express

If I need to see the incoming request headers I use: `req.headers`.

I need to see the list of all headers that will be in the response.

`res.headers` is `undefined`.

I know I can set response headers: `res.header('', '')`.

How do I view the response headers..?

Comment: did you try just calling the function with no parameters and seeing what it returns?

Comment: @nem035 Thanks.. `res.header()` returns an object with a `_headers` property. Whenever I've tried working with the `req`/`res` objects before they just fill my console window and I can't see the whole object. Thought someone might be able to point me quickly in the right direction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In recent versions of express there is:

```
res.getHeaders()

 -> {x-powered-by: "Express"}
```

Properties starting with "_" are not part of the official api. 
In case of changes, they will not be documented, and chances are the code will break.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [@nem035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3928341/nem035).

Response headers: `res.header()._headers`

Answer (score 10):

Also:

> ```
> res.get('Content-Type');
> // => "text/plain"
> ```
>
> https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.get

and, confusingly, lowercase is fine:

```
res.get('content-type');
// => "text/plain"

res.getHeaders()['content-type']
// => "text/plain"
```

Comment: Confusing to the developer, but not to the implementer. Headers are case insensitive, which is why implementers and vendors are falling back to lower case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Answer (score -2):

You Can Use This Method ...

```
/* ----------------------- Get Response Header By Name ---------------------- */
/* res.getHeader('Put Header Name Here'); */
/* For Example */
res.getHeader('x-powered-by');
```

---

This Method Help You To Get Response Header Name

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.