# express.Response setHeader for content type and type function

Tags: express

```
res.type(mime.lookup(path)) -> res is a type of express.Response
res.setHeader('Content-Type', mime.lookup(path))
```

Can I know are above two lines the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has same functionality to set `Content-Type` to response header.

Here documentation for `res.type`

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.type

And here documentation for `res.set`

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

Comment: I found the res.type is adding the charset at the end but the set is not. Is it possible to get the charset as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can test by calling api from client or using log on server, check more [View Express JS response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103565/view-express-js-response-headers)