# Why Django change requests header to uppercase?

Tags: django, django-views

I just want to know why django change requests header to uppercase ?

#### example :

i send headers

```
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36" ,
```

at backend django change it to

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

What's the need of this ?
Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: How do you catch these headers?

Answer (score 1):

`request.META` is a dictionary containing django's constants as keys, not HTTP header names.

I am [quoting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

> With the exception of **CONTENT_LENGTH** and **CONTENT_TYPE**, as given above,
>   any HTTP headers in the request are converted to **META** keys by
>   converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with
>   underscores and adding an **HTTP_** prefix to the name. So, for example, a
>   header called **X-Bender** would be mapped to the **META** key **HTTP_X_BENDER**.

Comment: I have edited  the question because its pycharm terminal bug .

Comment: It's worth noting that this is defined by the CGI spec (and by extension the WSGI spec), Django itself doesn't actually transform any of the headers. `request.META` is actually just the [WSGI `environ` variable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables).

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP headers are case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive).

[According to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), HTTP headers are converted to upper case, hyphens are converted to underscores, and the `HTTP_` prefix is added. This means that you can use `request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in your code, whether the request used `User-Agent`, `USER-AGENT`, or something else.