# How to add authorization on header using Swift 3.0 + Alamofire 4.0

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Am trying to add authorization to my header using a return apikey of my login user am trying like this but it seems to not working because am getting an error that apikey is missing (is a return error from the webservices)

```
 func getFavourites ()
{

    let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "authorization" : user.apiKey ]

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8888/food_pin/v1/restaurantToFavourites", method: HTTPMethod.get,  encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in


        if response.result.value != nil
        {
            print(response.result.value!)
            print(response.response!)
            self.returnAllFavourites(data: response.data!)
        }

        else
        {
            print(response.result.error!)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `Authorization`?

Comment: this is how it was written in my webservices i change it to capital just to see and you are right thank you

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Authorization` as your header key.

However, you shouldn't need to do it, considering [HTTP header keys are case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/2305521), the issue is probably on the server.