# getting message: forbidden reply from AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a lambda service on AWS and have it accessed from outside via the API gateway with no authentication or restriction required.

To make things easy I set the gateway for now to be a Mock.

On the Get method of the API, the Authorization is set to `None` and the API Key is `not required`.

When I try this, I get `{"message":"Forbidden"}`
(same message if I connect it to the actual lambda service).

Any advice on how to make it accessible?

Comment: Did you add get method before you deploy?

Comment: I wonder you don't have the correct invoke URL.

Comment: Thanks guys... indeed I had made a mistake in deployment.... feel dumb.

Comment: What was the mistake? How did you fix it?

Comment: I think I forgot to deploy or smt like that....

Comment: I can not vote down this question, but I would like to do it. "something-like-that" answers doesn't help the community. I have experimented forbidden messages because of bad indentation in my serverless.yml file.

Comment: anyone else landing here... the issue I had was not associating my API with a plan (which had the key attached to it).

Comment: Please select the checkmark next to the correct answer, rather than adding `[solved]` to your question. Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: How did you fix the problem? Just attached "solved" in your question is not helpful at all.

Comment: There is a well known issue when exporting and testing in Postman: the *basePath* variable always includes the backslash at the start, so you have double backslash in URL and thus API Gateway does not recognize the path and returns *forbidden*. Just delete the starting backslash from the basepath variable.

Answer (score 134):

If you have set `API Key Required` option to true, please check below:

1. You have to pass `x-api-key` HTTP Header Parameter to AWS API Gateway.
2. The API Key had to be created.
3. In addition, you need to check a Usage Plan for the API Key on AWS API Gateway Console.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your third step allow me to fix my error.

Comment: This worked for me, but it had to be 'X-Api-Key'  Looks like capitalization matters

Comment: All three steps did it for me. I had already created an API key but not linked it to a usage plan or anything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what should be value of x-api-key parameter?

Comment: Point 3 in your answer is often overlooked.  Turned out to be my problem.

Comment: How do I creat a usage plan?

Comment: @pixelwiz capitalization never matters regarding HTTP Header keys (names) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Comment: @Marecky, maybe it doesn't, but I promise you when I changed it, things started working in Postman where I was getting an error before.  Maybe it's less about HTTP Headers and more about how Postman processes them internally...

Comment: @pixelwiz It could be so, software often does not comply with standards :)

Comment: Huge thanks!  I, too, am a bit new to API Gateway.  I had added CORS, but didn't want to mess with my existing Stage, so I created a NEW Stage.  This HAS to be added to the API Key Usage Plan (select your Key and click Add API Stage here https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-1#/usage-plans).

Comment: @Marecky and pixelwiz, I was just dealing with a similar issue and to add to pixelwiz 's experience, I had the same issue.  After searching, I found that AWS API Gateway does have a 'known issue' whereby it does INDEED process headers in a 'case sensitive'.  Check out the bottom of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html

Comment: I was using x-app-key instead of x-api-key. it was a typo.

Comment: the `x-api-key` parameter initially looked like some kind of placeholder format. I was entering my API key name as the name of this parameter!

Comment: Snap 100% (3) was my problem in my CDK setup - legend! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Same problem. I had to add stage to my usage plan. Then it worked.

Answer (score 104):

On the API Gateway dashboard choose Resources, click Actions and choose Deploy API. Before your first deployment the only response you'll get is the `{"message":"Forbidden"}`.

Comment: I would add to this, after you deploy make sure that you add your stage name to the URL: abcdefg.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/STAGE_NAME/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the author explicitly said the API Key isn't required, and the current accepted answer solves that issue specifically.

Answer (score 59):

If you use a custom domain name and forget to select destination staging, you'll get the `Forbidden` message.

Simply go to `Custom Domain Names` and click `Edit` under your domain, and then select the stage under `Base Path Mappings`.

Comment: Works great and make sure to follow @jneves's answer and (re)deploy. after setting the mapping it didn't show up until I redeployed the stage I selected from the Base Path Mappings.

Comment: There is always a little missing piece! Thank you

Comment: this hidden hint just saved my day at work, thanks :)

Comment: This was it for me as well. Although they have updated the GUI here a bit. Now the correct area is to go into Custom Domain Names > API mappings

Answer (score 20):

You need to deploy your api on stage and use stage url go to Resources, click Actions and choose Deploy API

Now if you are getting error

> {"message":"Forbidden"}.

Please check following steps

1 ) If you enable api key copy and pass your key in postman

[image]

2) Now you still getting same error means you will need to create usage plan

[image]

3) set limit and assign plan to your api

[image]

Comment: can not see images

Answer (score 19):

I might be too late but one of the reasons API Gateway would give "forbidden" message is when you pass data in request Body on a GET operation. To solve the problem either make your resource POST or you do not pass data in request Body.

Comment: Was using Insomnia and changed my request from POST to GET.
Request type was still in `GraphQL Query` - which returned *403 Forbidden* Error.

Changing request type from `GraphQL Query` to `No Body` did the trick!

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: Well, thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

This may be far from obvious, but another reason of seeing "Forbidden" error when using AWS API Gateway may be calling incorrect URL that does not correspond to any deployed API method. It can occur if you're actually hitting wrong URL (e.g. instead of calling `https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users` (note `dev` stage before `users`) you called `https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/users` (no stage). You'd expect to get 404, but you'll get 403.

BTW: after you make a deployement to `https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users` calling `https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/user` (note singular noun form here) you'll get… 403 as well, but with "Missing Authentication Token" message!

Comment: This may be far from obvious, but another reason of seeing "Forbidden" error when using AWS API Gateway may be calling incorrect URL that does not correspond to any deployed API method. It can occur if you're actually hitting wrong URL (e.g. instead of calling https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users (note dev stage before users) you called https://9999xx9x99.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/users (no stage). You'd expect to get 404, but you'll get 403. How to solve this problem in ruby rack aws lambda api gateway endpoint?

Comment: @AnkitaDhandha, make a new question.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem, and I had the following:

1. A Custom Domain (Edge Optimized)
2. Multiple Stages (dev, staging, prod)

I also didn't set any Authorization nor restrictions to make things simple.

I was able to fix the problem by adding Base Path Mappings for each of my stages (dev, staging, prod).

Comment: I had the same basic setup w/ multiple APIs.  Interestingly, even though *only one* of my APIs was actually deployed, I received "Forbidden" until I set Base Path Mappings for the non-deployed APIs.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with custom domain and multiple stages but I deploy via CDK and different stacks per stage. Even if i deploy all stacks together i'm getting Forbidden in one of my stages. Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

If you set 'API' key required to true, you need to pass the api key as header.

API Key is passed as header field 'x-api-key'. Even after adding this field in header, this issue may occur. In that case, please validate below points

- Do you have a Usage Plan? if not need to create one.
- Link you API with Usage Plan. For that add a stage, it will link your API.
- Do you have API Key? if not you need to create an API Key and enable it.
- Add the Usage Plan which is linked with your API to this API Key. For that add Usage Plan.

Answer (score 6):

The only other reason that I've experienced which I don't see mentioned here is literally that you tried to reach the API too quickly after being published.  I hit publish and see the "your API is reachable at" domain name, and immediately copy and pasted that into Postman to check it.

I get the forbidden message.  Change nothing.  Check all settings to ensure that I haven't done anything - everything is correct.  Kinda tearing my hair out.

Return a few minutes later to try because I'm quite sure I'm doing it all correct - it works.

DNS man.  No matter how fast the Internet is - it ain't instant :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was because I used the

> Managed-AllViewer

origin request policy. Switching to

> Managed-UserAgentRefererHeaders

solved the problem.

My client sent an `Accept-Encoding` header, which CloudFront did not like. You can verify this by creating a custom origin request policy of type "Whitelist", and although `Accept-Encoding` is selectable from the list, you receive an error when creating the policy: `"The parameter Headers contains Accept-Encoding that is not allowed."`

I did not find the relevant documentation unfortunately. Also no clue why such an inconspicuous header is disallowed.

Comment: This solved my issue. Could run all methods via the invoke on API Gateway, however when I ran the same methods in Postman to test, I got a 403 for all POST methods.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the options to look into:

"Why do I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden error when connecting to my API Gateway APIs from a VPC?"

If you have "private dns" enabled, and you use a VPCEndpoint, you might very well run into this issue. See: [Why do I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden error when connecting to my API Gateway APIs from a VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/)

In my case, I had two API Gateways in the same account:

- a public  HTTP API Gateway fronting a Lambda function,
- a private REST API Gateway fronting a lambda function (with a VPCEndpoint so that my ECS/Fargate containers could talk to the private API)

The problem was that once I set up the private API+VPCEndpoint, it started to siphon all traffic FROM WITHIN AWS to API Gateways (so, both to my public and to my private API Gateways). And that broke the PUBLIC HTTP API.

I banged my head for some time because, from my laptop, I could reach the public API Gateway but NOT from my docker container inside AWS Fargate!

The possible solutions are:

- Option 1: add a Route53 to the public API if you need to call it from your docker container (that way, your container makes an outbound "internet request" and back into the public gateway [~from outside])
- Option 2: for the public API, I ended up going for a simpler option: I got rid of the public API and, instead, exposed my Lambda function through an Application Load Balancer: just need to configure the TargetGroup to point to Lambda.

I now have:

- my Private REST API Gateway (and VPCEndpoint) that fronts the Lambda function for my docker containers (those run in AWS/Fargate in private subnets)
- my Publicly available ALB to reach the Lambda function (not using HTTP API Gateway anymore for this).

Comment: this is indeed what happens. it is really hard to detect this issue. to be honest, aws documentation (the link that you send) not very well written. It is mentioning about VPC, Api Gateway etc. but does not tell you whether it is VPC of caller, or VPC of API Gateway etc. very confusing.

Comment: The AWS docs often link to many other docs that then lead to other docs. It's always hard to find a good overall doc that explains all combinations (I understand AWS' troubles, it's hard to document all options so they end up with a nightmare of hyperlinks). I found that ChatGPT is very useful to ask general AWS questions (not always totally accurate but often manages to make sense of all the hyperlinked info and generates a pretty good idea of what the solution probably looks like).

Answer (score 4):

If `Authorization` and `API KEY Required` both are set to true for the method, then make sure you have the following Headers while sending the request:

1. Content-Type (usually application/x-www-form-urlencoded if GET call)
2. HOST
3. X-Amz-Date
4. Authorization
5. X-Api-Key

I use `POSTMAN` for API testing which is quite reliable and then it's preety straight forward.

Note: Do not add X-Api-Key header if you have set `API KEY REQUIRED` as FALSE.
And if you have set `AUTHORIZATION` as FALSE then do not add Authorization header.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to do when we receive the {message: forbidden} in the API Gateway:

**CORS enabled?**

1. Check if CORS is Enabled within the API ( to start with, allow the origin '*', to make sure we can test safely )
2. Deploy the API to make sure all settings are as expected

**API Key enabled?**

3. Check if we have the API Key enabled in the API Gateway
4. Check if there is an API Key configured.
5. Check if your API Key is assigned to the correct usageplan and add an API Stage, without the API Stage you will always receive an {message: forbidden}

If you are still facing issues, let me know so me or one of our cloud gurus @levarne can help.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was connected to my office's VPN which routes into my company's VPC in AWS. My company had private DNS setup which resulted in the request to the public endpoint being routed to a private IP address belonging to the VPC's interface endpoint for API Gateway.

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/) explains it all.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Turn off VPN when hitting the invoke URL.
2. Use API Gateway custom domain.

I ended up using solution 1 because I needed to setup a cloudfront in front of API Gateway and the custom domain I want to use was already setup as Edge type with other api gateways associated with it.

For additional reference, Edge type custom domains cannot be set as the origin of another cloudfront because it uses CloudFront to speed up connections across all geographic locations. See [this AWS support article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error from an nginx fargate service trying to access a private API in API Gateway.  I needed to add a policy under resource policies in my api like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<AccountID>:<RestApiID>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "<VPC Endpoint ID for execute-api>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I might have come across a solution to this problem.
I had the same issue right now on MacOS.
I tried to **flush my DNS** and then it worked!

Try this in the terminal:

Mac OS X Yosemite and later

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Mac OS X Yosemite v10.10 through v10.10.3

```
sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache
```

Mac OS X Mavericks, Mountain Lion and Lion

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Mac OS X Snow Leopard

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on the similar case I ran into with Swagger Editor:

- I exported the OpenAPI 3.0 YAML from API Gateway → Stages → select "Prod" → select "Export" tab → switch radiobutton to "OpenAPI 3" → "Export as OpenAPI 3 + API Gateway Extensions"
- Paste the received YAML to https://editor.swagger.io/
- Execute a trivial GET method.
- It returns `403 Forbidden` with `{"message":"Forbidden"}` body.

`curl` command from Swagger Editor looked like this:

`curl -X GET "https://xxx52xxxx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com//Prod/users" -H  "accept: application/json"`

(note the double `//` before `Prod`).

And the same `curl` command without `//` worked via the command line!

The trick that worked is to replace this `server` structure returned in the API Gateway-generated:

```
servers:
  - url: "https://xxx52xxxx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{basePath}"
    variables:
      basePath:
        default: "/Prod"
```

With the full `url` without `variables`:

```
servers:
  - url: "https://xxx52xxxx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod"
```

Notably, removing the leading slash from `default: "/Prod"` didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Local Firewall / antivirus or NGIPS (**Cisco Bluecoat**). The latter was my case, where I wouldn't even get logs in CloudWatch from my API. It was allowing my top level domain hosted website, but was blocking with 403 the `api` subdomain, with no body in the browser's network dev-tools tab.

Answer (score 1):

I got `{"message":"Forbidden"}` on an API with EndpointConfiguration set to PRIVATE, and a VpcEndpoint created for it in the Vpc's private subnets (this is an inter-service API)

The reason I got `{"message":"Forbidden"}` was that I was under the impression I should use one of the VpcEndpoint's urls. The URL to use is still the one associated with the stage (in ApiGateway console). It is:

`https://${RestApiId}.execute-api.${Region}.amazonaws.com/${StageName}`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Turned out that my certificate in Certificate Manager was not created in North Virginia region (*us-east-1*), therefore I could not mark Custom Domain as Edge-optimized. I had to choose Regional instead.

When I re-imported the certificate using N. Virginia region and created a Custom Domain again, but this time with Edge-optimized endpoint configuration, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This usually comes when we try to access the Private API endpoint with incorrect policy & without passing the 'HOST' header in the invoke request.
Let's say I have an API that is deployed as a private endpoint with the below resource policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:12345678:2ucqasdfasdfryc/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:12345678:2dgaucqt6dfgdyc/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-87878kjlkj8787k"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Accessing Private API endpoint when private-DNS-hostnames disabled.

```
curl -v -H 'Host: 01234567ab.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' https://vpce-01234567abcdef012-01234567.execute-api.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/test/pets
```

[OR]
use the `API ID` instead of the `Host` header.

```
curl -v -H 'x-apigw-api-id: 01234567' https://vpce-01234567abcdef012-01234567.execute-api.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/test/pets
```

Answer (score 1):

I received this error today because the aws_host in the signing header was incorrect (using Boto3 and AWSRequestAuth).

While refactoring I started to loop through multiple requests, but this introduced request was on a different API that required a different aws_host.

```
auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key=credentials.access_key,
                       aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
                       aws_token=credentials.token,
                       aws_host=f'api.{env}.XXX.dk',
                       aws_region=region,
                       aws_service='execute-api')
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that I had `API Key Source` set to `AUTHORIZER` in the API Settings but did not have any authorizer defined.

[API Key Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpF3p.png)

(this was due to my reuse of a CDK construct where this was set

```
    let restApiConfig: RestApiProps = {
      restApiName: apiName,
      apiKeySourceType: ApiKeySourceType.AUTHORIZER,   // <-- Should be HEADER
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: deployEnv,
...
```

)

Don't forget to redeploy the API if manually applying the change.

Answer (score 0):

We had faced this issue in our production when we used Kong as our api gateway. Our requests passed thro when initiated from Postman but failed with 403 when initiated via Code. The Bot plugin in Kong was enabled which only allowed requests initiated from Browser or Mobile App based on the user agent header value.Our requests initiated via Http Client failed. Once we disabled the bot plugin then the error didnt occur. It now allows request if the user-agent is Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_91).

Answer (score 0):

Putting my experience over here as well. I tried all those things above and it turned out that putting the domain with a wildcard solved my  **{"message":"Forbidden"}** issue: *.mydomain.com

[image: Custom domain]

Answer (score 0):

> As @gary69 and @Adriaan Pelzer mentions
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727654/809043
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136675/809043
>
> You can get the message {"message":"Forbidden"} when requesting a
> Private API.

So if you have a setup where all traffic should go thorough a API Endpoint which than directs the traffic to the API Gateway then the following parameters may be used.

```
APIGatewayVPCEndpoint:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument: '{
        "Version":"2012-10-17",
        "Statement":[{
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action":["execute-api:Invoke"],
          "Resource":["arn:aws:execute-api:eu-north-1:000000000000:*/*"]
        }]
      }'
  ...
  VpcEndpointType: Interface
  PrivateDnsEnabled: true
```

If PrivateDnsEnabled is enabled, than the endpoint in the API Gateway needs to be of Type Private, and a policy needs to added.

```
  ApiGatewayRest:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Description: A mocked API
      Name: Mocked API
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
      Policy: '{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-north-1:000000000000:*/*/*/*"
        }]
      }'
```

This forum thread helped clear out some of the details for me

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=286760

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue a week back and spent sometime to identify the issue. Our api gateway endpoint has been configured to work only through public network and we have a WAF & resource policy to filter the incoming requests to the endpoint. I was able to access the endpoint from a different vpc and not from a particular vpc. I was getting Forbidden error.

At last, found that the vpc that i was trying from, have the VPC Endpoint for the execute api service with private DNS enabled. API Gateway endpoint was resolving to a private IP inside the VPC.

There are two ways to resolve it. One, we can disable the private DNS, which is what I did. It started working very fine after the change. But we have to make sure it doesn't affect others who are using the vpc endpoint.

Two, we can use a custom domain name & we can use that to call from the vpc.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was about the setting the API Keys to "not required". I followed a couple of the steps listed in the answers here, but the main thing I was forgetting to do because I am not familiar with API Gateway was that I had to REDEPLOY the api after I set the API key as "not required".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you get 403. One of reasons is [this issue](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/#:%7E:text=Short%20description,to%20that%20interface%20VPC%20endpoint.)

To sum up the root cause:

> When a private DNS is enabled on a VPC endpoint, the API's invoke URL is covered by the private DNS name *.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com where * is a placeholder for the API ID. When a DNS query is resolved for a public API from inside a VPC, the resolved DNS points to the private IP of the associated VPC endpoint instead of the public IP of the public API. The API call is then routed to the public API through the VPC endpoint instead of routing it through the internet. Because VPC endpoints can route traffic only to private APIs, the result is an HTTP 403 error.

If you are running a lambda within in a VPC that has API Gateway VPC endpoint, then you will get 403. You can run lambda function without VPC

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a simple mistake while calling the API. I was using curl and I set the header using `x-api-key:xxxxxxxxxxx` and when I call it with `x-api-key: xxxxxxxxxx`, it works. A simple space was missing in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using multiple API gateways and API mappings created with SAM. The custom domain was created via terraform. All the REST API gateways worked fine but the one that was HTTP API returned 403 with the message "Forbidden".

Turns out you have to use the Domain name v2 to be able to mix both (see the little note at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-custom-domain-names.html)

Changing my terraform ressource from aws_api_gateway_domain_name to aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name made it work.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the api key was not enable. 
Make sure the API is set as Enabled.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue
I was able to resolve it by adding a "/" at end of the URL

eg.
https://xxx52xxxx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello

gave error `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

but https://xxx52xxxx9.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello/

gave required output