# AWS api gateway get by id returns 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a lamdba function using java 8. I refer to [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-java). I try to create a REST API get endpoint. Get by id in particular. I want to have an endpoint like `/objects/{objectId}`. I get an 403 response with `"message": "Missing Authentication Token"`. Shouldn't it populate `proxy` of `pathParameters` as the value of objectId? What I missed?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `API Key`. Does this previous answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988051/getting-message-forbidden-reply-from-aws-api-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have configured the API Gateway correctly.[image]