# Why would I get a Forbidden message from AWS API Gateway, even though things are working internally?

Tags: python, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, locust

I have AWS API gateway setup for a public endpoint with no auth. It connects to a websocket that triggers a Lambda.

I was creating connections with Python's `websocket-client` lib at https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/.

I noticed that connections would fail ~10% of the time, and get worse as I increased load. I can't find anywhere that would be throttling me seeing as my general API Gateway settings say `Your current account level throttling rate is 10000 requests per second with a burst of 5000 requests.`. That’s beside the point that just 2-3 requests per second would trigger issue fairly often.

Meanwhile the failure response would be like `{u'message': u'Forbidden', u'connectionId': u'Z2Jp-dR5vHcCJkg=', u'requestId': u'Z2JqAEJRvHcFzvg='}`

I went into my CloudWatch log insights and searched for the connection ID and request ID. The log group for the API gateway would find no results with either ID. Yet a search on my Lambda that fires on websocket connect, would have a log with that connection ID. The log showed everything running as expected on our side. The lambda simply runs a MySQL query that fires.

Why would I get a response of forbidden, despite the lambda working as expected?

The existing question over at [getting message: forbidden reply from AWS API gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988051/getting-message-forbidden-reply-from-aws-api-gateway), seems to address if it's ALWAYS returning forbidden for some private endpoints. Nothing lined up with my use case.

**UPDATE**

I think this may be related to `locust.io`, or python, which I'm using to connect every second. I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat on my machine and am connecting and closing as fast as possible repeatedly. I am not getting a `Forbidden` message. It's just extra confusing since I'm not sure how the way I connect would randomly spit back a `Forbidden` message *some of the time*.

```py
class SocketClient(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host
        self.session_id = uuid4().hex

    def connect(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        self.ws.settimeout(10)
        self.ws.connect(self.host)

        events.quitting += self.on_close

        data = self.attach_session({})
        return data

    def attach_session(self, payload):
        message_id = uuid4().hex
        start_time = time.time()
        e = None
        try:
            print("Sending payload {}".format(payload))
            data = self.send_with_response(payload)
            assert data['mykey']

        except AssertionError as exp:
            e = exp
        except Exception as exp:
            e = exp
            self.ws.close()
            self.connect()
        elapsed = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
        if e:
            events.request_failure.fire(request_type='sockjs', name='send',
                                        response_time=elapsed, exception=e)
        else:
            events.request_success.fire(request_type='sockjs', name='send',
                                        response_time=elapsed,
                                        response_length=0)
        return data

    def send_with_response(self, payload):
        json_data = json.dumps(payload)

        g = gevent.spawn(self.ws.send, json_data)
        g.get(block=True, timeout=2)
        g = gevent.spawn(self.ws.recv)
        result = g.get(block=True, timeout=10)

        json_data = json.loads(result)
        return json_data
    def on_close(self):
        self.ws.close()

class ActionsTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def streams(self):
        response = self.client.connect()
        logger.info("Connect Response: {}".format(response))

class WSUser(Locust):
    task_set = ActionsTaskSet
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 3000

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WSUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = SocketClient('wss://mydomain.amazonaws.com/endpoint')
```

[image]

**Update 2**

I have enabled access logs, the one type of log that wasn't there before. I can now see that my lambdas are always getting a 200 with no issue. The 403 is coming from some `MESSAGE` `eventType` that doesn't hit an actual `routeKey`. Not sure where it comes from, but pretty sure finding that answer will solve this.

I was also able to confirm there are no ENI issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload in my example is empty. The API is configured to use `$request.body.action` to know the routeKey. Connecting makes the default `$connect` route work.

Adding a proper `action` in my body made the 403s go away. This is the solution. I was essentially getting 200 responses from the act of connecting and disconnecting, but was getting the 403 whenever my message without a payload went through.

Answer (score 4):

You might be running into some VPC-related limits. See https://winterwindsoftware.com/scaling-lambdas-inside-vpc/. Sounds like you might be running out of ENIs. You could try moving the function to a different VPC. How long does each invocation of the lambda run for? And what language is you lambda written in?

Comment: My timeout is set to 6 seconds. The average duration is 70ms. Since my test is running at 1-3 a second and running into this, could I possibly be running out of ENIs?

Comment: My current limit is 350 for Network Interfaces and 5 for VPC security groups per elastic network interface. My unreserved account concurrency for a lambda is 1000

Comment: Also, I'm thinking I get a `Forbidden` from gateway during a spinup, but that doesn't explain the many `Forbidden`s I get in less than 6 seconds, after getting success, while running 2 a second.

Comment: I see this got 4 upvotes,but I have not hit any limits. Certainly not ENIs, as confirmed by AWS support. My last update, showing the `routeKey` issue should confirm this isn't the issue at hand.