# Api gateway keeps returning forbidden

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-batch

First off:
Yes I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988051/getting-message-forbidden-reply-from-aws-api-gateway) already and I'm pretty sure I have done all the things described.

That said; I am currently in a situation where I try to get AWS api gateway up and running serving as a fornt-end to the batch jobs queue's. My final result would be something like making a post that would trigger the creation of a batch job in a specific queue.

I now have an REST API gateway setup with a userrole that is able to run batch jobs and also has full access to EC2 and api gateway. When I run a mock service and/or a dummy HTTP service all goes well. I get either my custom message or the mock message of status 200.

No matter what I try however I always get the same response (both in the UI as well as in Postman):

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I have the API key enabled as well as CORS. Furthermore I am not limiting this by means of waf and/or firewall ruling. It is directly connected to the internet. I have setup a usage plan which covers my tests as well.

I have isolated my problem to the interaction with the batch module. When I use a mock service on the same API I get no errors.

The very minimal situation I could come up with is asking for the job definitions or queues which I took from [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobQueues.html). This can be seen in this screenshot from the Integration Request tab:
[image]

Having done pretty much everything in the link at the top of this post I am out of options and/or ways to get this right.

What important thing am I missing?

Comment: How are you running the "mock service and/or a dummy HTTP service"?  Do you get the 403 if you hit the endpoint from Postman (or another package sending utility)?

Comment: Hi @AmosLong: This issue was from august and I have since abandoned it in favor of a different route. I can't really recall the details of my setup either. Still thanks for your response.

Comment: For future travelers: Note that in the DescribeJobQueues function documentation, the method is a POST method (the screenshot in the OP specifies GET). This may have had something to do with it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobQueues.html - HOWEVER...unfortunately I am getting the same error even with the POST method :/. Sigh.

Comment: Some steps I'm trying...check the IAM policy simulator to make sure it's not an IAM issue: https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp

Comment: Ah...I think it's likely due to the need for a VPC Endpoint...

Comment: Nope, not VPC Endpoint...