# {'message': 'Forbidden'} instead of returning Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, algorithmic-trading

I'm making a CoinBasePro TradingBot and I've got some error with trying to make a position.

```
class Trader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.public = 'Public'
        self.passphrase = 'Passphrase'
        self.secret = 'Secret'
        self.auth_client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(key= self.public, b64secret= self.secret, passphrase= self.passphrase)
```

Then, there is some RSI calculation function (float output) and direction function.

Next thing is to make a position function:

```
def make_pos(self, ticker):
    rsi = self.RSI_calc(ticker)
    direction = self.set_direction(ticker)
    if rsi <= 42 and direction == 'buy':
        position = self.auth_client.place_market_order(product_id= ticker, side=direction, size= self.QUANTITY)
        print(position)
```

You know, it should output something like *{
"id": "d0c5340b-6d6c-49d9-b567-48c4bfca13d2",
"price": "0.10000000",
"size": "0.01000000",
"product_id": "BTC-USD",
"side": "buy",
"stp": "dc",
"type": "limit",
"time_in_force": "GTC",
"post_only": false,
"created_at": "2016-12-08T20:02:28.53864Z",
"fill_fees": "0.0000000000000000",
"filled_size": "0.00000000",
"executed_value": "0.0000000000000000",
"status": "pending",
"settled": false
}*

, but it returns **{'message': 'Forbidden'}**

Any hints please?

My thanks.

Comment: authorization fails. are the keys correct?

Comment: Fix indentation after class definition.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the dictionary. It is an API problem. Whatever API you are using is returning a forbidden error that is being printed. If you fix that, you'll get the results there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988051/getting-message-forbidden-reply-from-aws-api-gateway

Comment: Your client isn't being authenticated or you don't have permission for that endpoint. I would double check your credentials would be my first guess

Comment: maybe read the api documentation and see the response/message code

Comment: Nice, it was because of the api key, now I am trying to buy and code colapses, because of :
{'message': 'Limit only mode'}

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. People will not see your comment buried in a list of comments here.