# Axios posts as JSON object, how to change

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

As the title states, when you do a

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The data will be in a JSON object, and thus will not be detected by `$_REQUEST`, and can only be found in `php://input`.

Is there anyway to change this? I've tried changing the `content-type` as well, but that didn't help.

Comment: axios uses JSON as default content type. In [this URL](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/97) you can find several workarounds and solutions for this problem.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow and let you know the results

Comment: Well as long as it helps :)

Comment: -1 because HTTP headers are NOT case sensitive; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Comment: @KBoek Yes by RFC definition they are not but at the time of my answer there was a problem with lowercase headers using this library. I just checked it and now it works as per RFC so updating my answer. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Fma, OK, I reversed the -1 :)

Comment: did you resolved it ?

Answer (score 14):

Here is what is explained on the [github axios page](https://github.com/axios/axios):

By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use one of the following options.

*Browser*

In a browser, you can use the URLSearchParams API as follows:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

Note that URLSearchParams is not supported by all browsers (see caniuse.com), but there is a polyfill available (make sure to polyfill the global environment).

*Alternatively*, you can encode data using the qs library:

```
const qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
```

*Or in another way (ES6)*,

```
import qs from 'qs';
const data = { 'bar': 123 };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options);
```

Comment: Using a mix of `urlsearchparams` and the `data` property must also work: `var params=new URLSearch...;options=...data: params`. But it does not work, in the error the data property is empty. I want to use GoogleTrans of [Rapidapi](https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1/)

Comment: Although in the RapdiApi Example it is done with `urlsearchparams` it did not work. But with `qs` in ES6 it works.