# Mechanize in Python Changes HTTP headers case

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to automate a web page request by using mechanize in python. 
When I add custom headers like
`X-Session= 'abc'`
 and
`X-Auth='123'`
by using addheader function.

```
object=mechanize.Browser()
object.addheaders=[('X-Session','abc'),('X-Auth','123')]
```

It changes those headers to `X-session` and `X-auth`. 
I believe due to that the server is not able to authenticate me. 
Can anybody help how to maintain the case?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive says that http headers are case-insensitive. What makes you say it could be due to case that server isnt authenticating your request?

Comment: Yes right, but since it is a custom header the implementation on the server side may not deal with case insensitivity. It might be checking with the original header.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize expect two items tuple as header, first item is header name, second is value, so you must do:

```
object.addheaders=[('X-Session','abc'), ('X-Auth','123')]
```

(Two tuples of two elements instead of one tuple with 4 elements).

---

To check headers that Mechanize will send with query, you can do:

```
print(request.header_items())
```

This should print something like:

```
[('X-Session','abc'), ('X-Auth','123')]
```

---

Doc: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#adding-headers

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and yes i had make it like a tuple only as you stated above, I will update the code which is a typo. Also when i print request.header_items() it shows "X-Session" as "X-session".