# Http outbound gateway is manipulating the header value

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring-Integration in our project. I am experiencing a weird problem with  `http:outbound-gateway`. We need to pass the following headers for executing a rest service.
1)`Accept=application/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml`

2)`Content-Type=application/xml`

The weird part is that the response returned is not always unique, In dev environment, xml response(`Content-Type=application/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml`) is returned while in client environment, json response(`Content-Type=application/vnd.dsths.services-v1+json`) is returned. I have verified the log files by turning on `DEBUG` and found that the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` is Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json,  */` * ].

```
2017-07-10 16:17:11,563 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] (ajp-/10.226.55.163:8009-1) Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
```

I could able to overcome this problem by overriding the value of `accept=*/*` to `accept=application/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml` in the client environment(Please note that this header is not the actual "`Accept`" header).

The question here is why `http:outbound-gateway` is behaving oddly and manipulating the header value? Why the Spring Integration is not able to identify the difference between the headers and `"accept"` and `"Accept"`? Is my fix correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the question about *difference*, but according RFC-2616 HTTP headers are case-insensitive: [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive).

And `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` follow that recommendations:

```
private void setHttpHeader(HttpHeaders target, String name, Object value) {
    if (ACCEPT.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        if (value instanceof Collection<?>) {
```

What you show is the part of Spring MVC already, far away from Spring Integration. See `RestTemplate` code:

```
public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        if (this.responseType != null) {
            Class<?> responseClass = null;
            if (this.responseType instanceof Class) {
                responseClass = (Class<?>) this.responseType;
            }
            List<MediaType> allSupportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
            for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : getMessageConverters()) {
                if (responseClass != null) {
                    if (converter.canRead(responseClass, null)) {
                        allSupportedMediaTypes.addAll(getSupportedMediaTypes(converter));
                    }
                }
                else if (converter instanceof GenericHttpMessageConverter) {
                    GenericHttpMessageConverter<?> genericConverter = (GenericHttpMessageConverter<?>) converter;
                    if (genericConverter.canRead(this.responseType, null, null)) {
                        allSupportedMediaTypes.addAll(getSupportedMediaTypes(converter));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!allSupportedMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
                MediaType.sortBySpecificity(allSupportedMediaTypes);
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Setting request Accept header to " + allSupportedMediaTypes);
                }
                request.getHeaders().setAccept(allSupportedMediaTypes);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you see the logic is based on the provided `HttpMessageConverter` and it is, honestly, is correct. The `Accept` header is exactly what the client can handle from the server.

If you don't like such a behavior and you are sure in your client, you can inject `RestTemplate` to the `http:outbound-gateway` but already with only desired `HttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation. I am thinking that MessageBuilder.removeHeader("accept") should work so that the correct header `Accept` can be recognized by Spring framework. Does that make sense or do you foresee any other problems?

Comment: ??? You fully don't understand me. Do I talk about removing some header? I explain you how there are those values for the `Accept` and how to overcome that. Your `Accept` header from the Spring Integration does not have any effect and it is overridden in the `RestTemplate` anyway.