# Header keys become lowercase when interacting with API - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch-api

When interacting with API, the custom Header key always become lowercase. I'm use `Fetch`, `Axios`, `XMLHttpRequest` and `Frisbee` (javascript network library) but the key always lowercase

My snippet code like this (with `fetch()` method), The key I'm push is: **'Token-Api'** but the server receive: **'token-api'**, so it's show the error 401. It's work with Postman:

```
 const request = 'https://abcxyz';
 fetch(request, {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Token-Api':'...abcxyz....'
   }
 }).then((response) => {
            log(abcxyz)
        })...
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can read this post: [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/2444365)

According to RFC 2616, HTTP headers should be case-insensitive. So this is not the bug of the libraries you mention above. You should fix the server to treat `Token-Api` and `token-api` at the same way.

Comment: It may not be considered a bug, still the fact the headers are case-insentive does not mean anyone may feel free to change the case (to me, at least). I'm wondering if are the libs to manipulate the case or the browser(s).

Answer (score -6):

You can actually solve this quite easily with another header:

`sensitive: true`