# How to change uppercase/lowercase in phantomJS http request headers?

Tags: python, http-headers, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am scraping a pool of URLs in a python/selenium setup using phantomJS and custom http headers.

Some specific URLs block the request and forward it to `dontuseabot.css`.

However, when I manually edit the capitalization of some header fields and replay/reissue the request using Fiddler, I can reach the URL of interest without seeing `dontuseabot.css`.

Since http headers are [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive), how to force uppercase/lowercase in phantomJS request header fields? Setting up a rule in Fiddler seems like an inefficient solution - similar to patching phantomJS.

Comment: You could download PhantomJS sources, fix headers case and then build a binary, but using a proxy to correct headers is probably a simpler solution.

Comment: It is hard to believe that noone did this already - is there something like an inventory list of availlable phantomJS patches?

Comment: There are a dozen of pull requests: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pulls Please note that PhantomJS is not  actively developed anymore since there is [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)