# How to extract token string from Bearer token?

Tags: node.js, jwt

For example I have following Bearer JWT in my header, what's a elegant way to extract the token itself? Basically anything after `Bearer`. Since this could be in other formats, I don't want to assume it always starts with `Bearer`. I'm using [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) and I didn't find such method.

`Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9...TJVA95OrM7E20RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can split with space using

```
TokenArray = jwttoken.split(" ");
```

it will store in an array form where the 2nd index ( 1 as first index is 0) `TokenArray[1]`  will be the token and use

```
Jwt.decode(TokenArray[1])
```

to decode the token 
JWT is a token standard which you can use in many ones and one of the  most used case of this is for authorization and it can be done in many ways too but the prefered standard way is sending it in a bearer authorisation header
You can use`refresh_token` instead to `bearer token` but you have to store the token somewhere which will somehow reduced the effeciency of the term `stateless` token . So the bearer approch is completly stateless and a prefered approach

Comment: Be careful please with decode as it doesn't verify if the token is valid, use verify instead and handle the rejection if it's invalid

Answer (score 95):

For security reasons you should make sure that the Authorization header has the expected content. You simply should not accept a header that does not start with `Bearer` if you are expecting it ("Bearer" is a recommendation in the RFC, it is not mandatory) ".

```
if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
     token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);
} else {
   //Error
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a function for extracting the token from the request header or the query. I post it here. Hope it helps someone.

```
function extractToken (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
        return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You call split() twice, which is inefficient.

Comment: @hirikarate it's more efficient than declaring a variable to store the split result.

Comment: @Sinandro depends on what you're talking about. It's ostensibly more memory efficient but that depends on how .split is written. It's absolutely not more time efficient.

Answer (score 9):

For typescript, nodejs, import **jwt-decode**.

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

    const authHeader = String(req.headers['authorization'] || '');
    if (authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      const token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);
      const payload = jwtDecode(token) as JwtPayload;
    }
```

**JwtPayload** is an interface or a class.

```
export interface JwtPayload {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  role: string;
  expire: number;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple utility function which returns token

```
function getToken(req) {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
  ) {
    return req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  } 
  return null;
}
```

Then the token can be passed to other methods. For example, verifying the signature.

```
  const token = getToken(req);

  if (!token) {
    throw new Error("Authorization token is required");
  } 
 jwt.verify(token, secret, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error("Error : " + err);
    }
    console.log(decoded);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

since your authorization header is always preceded with "Bearer " you can use try this :

```
 String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length);
```

this would return the rest of the content of Authorization header , i hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

this is my version for safe and clean code for typescript to parse bearer.

```
        // parse token bearer
        const tokenBearer = req?.headers?.authorization ? (() => {
            const authHeader = <string>req?.headers?.authorization || ``
            const [code,token] = authHeader.trim().split(` `)
            if (code !== `Bearer`)
                return void 0
            else
                return token
        })() : void 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in TypeScript which is way cleaner than most of the answers I saw here.

```
export const parseBearer = (bearer: string) => {
  const [_, token] = bearer.trim().split(" ");
  return token;
};
```

Basically truncating the bearer string, splitting by space and then getting the element(token) at the index of one.

To handle the token all you will have to do is to verify it using a package such as [`jsonwebtoken`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). Final result will look something like this:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"

const authorizationHeader = req.headers["Authorization"];
const token = parseBearer(authorizationHeader);

try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);
    return res.json(decoded);
} catch (error: any) {
    return res.status(403).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
}
```

Comment: req.headers["authorization"]

Comment: @PranuPranav can you explain your comment please?

Comment: @ggorlen It is the typo in the headers field.

Comment: Are you trying to suggest it should be lowercase? If so, I've always seen it uppercased. Please share some evidence to support your claim.

Comment: I saw it in express request if I console.log({ headers: req.headers });  For your reference a screen shot included: https://ibb.co/gStgQYx

Comment: @PranuPranav you can read [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive) where they more thoroughly discuss the case-sensitive/insensitive parts of the HTTP protocol. Usually, both ways work, however, in Node.js specifically the headers are automatically converted to lowercase. More information about this can be found on the following page: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#method-url-and-headers. My example does not introduce anything that would break one's code, since it is also works.

Comment: @ordinaryduck yes. I just checked the postman request header it is Authorization. in express req.header it is authorization. I am confused. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions may help.

```js
const header = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9";

const extractedAuth =
  header?.match(/^(?<type>.+?)\s+(?<token>.+?)$/)?.groups ?? {
    type: "none"
  };
console.log(extractedAuth);

// then you can perform your actions like:
switch (extractedAuth.type.toLowerCase()) {
  case "bearer":
    console.log("Auth scheme is Bearer and the token is", extractedAuth.token);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`const jwtString = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The most universal solution that I came up with (you can adjust 'needle' according to your needs):

```
const authHeader = 'Bearer mytokengoeshere OtherThing...';
const needle = 'Bearer ';
const bearerAt = authHeader.indexOf(needle);
const spaceAfterTokenAt = authHeader.indexOf(' ', needle.length);
const token = authHeader.slice(
    bearerAt + needle.length,
    spaceAfterTokenAt > -1 ? spaceAfterTokenAt : authHeader.length
);
```

You can drop spaceAfterTokenAt logic at all in case if you sure that you authorization header would be just as simple as 'Bearer mytokengoeshere' string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
const token = authHeader && authHeader.replace(/^Bearer\s+/, '');
```

The regular expression `/^Bearer\s+/` matches the Bearer keyword at the beginning of the string followed by one or more whitespace characters. The `replace()` function removes this pattern from the string, leaving only the JWT token.

This approach is more secure because it ensures that the Authorization header has the expected format (Bearer ), and prevents potential exploits that could occur if an attacker were to manipulate the header value to inject malicious content.

Answer (score -1):

//When token is String, i saw that have " before and end of string, so i have to remove " from token as below
// Add the Authorization header with the AccessToken.

```
            token = token.Substring(1, token.Length-2);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Comment: This is pretty odd. Usually strings don't have quotes _literally in_ them on the ends, just as delimiters for purposes of code and display Are you sure your client isn't sending a bad request with extra quotes? Also, the code is broken here. Is this supposed to be JS?