# HttpHeaders getFirst() case insensitivity

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, resttemplate

I'm fetching HTTP headers with Spring's RestTemplate.

[HTTP headers are case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive), but the [documentation for HttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) doesn't seem to acknowledge this.

A quick test shows that things are working as expected...

```
HttpHeaders headers = restTemplate.headForHeaders(url);
Long a = Long.parseLong(headers.getFirst("Content-Length"));
Long b = Long.parseLong(headers.getFirst("content-length"));
assert( a.equals(b) ); // passes
```

Can I be sure that this test will pass under all Spring configurations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/95a84bbad1dc04954376ff2d4f40ab233923522a) it is explicitly stated that [`HttpHeaders`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) are case-insensitive:

> Note that `HttpHeaders` generally treats header names in a case-insensitive manner.

---

**Old answer**

`HttpHeaders` has only one public constructor and its body:

```
public HttpHeaders() {
    this(new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<>(8, Locale.ENGLISH), false);
}
```

And according to `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.html):

> LinkedHashMap variant that stores String keys in a case-insensitive manner, for example for key-based access in a results table.
>
> Preserves the original order as well as the original casing of keys, **while allowing for contains, get and remove calls with any case of key**.

So yes, it always works in case insensitive manner.

But why you do not use [HttpHeaders#getContentLength()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#getContentLength--)? :

```
// no need to convert String to long
long contentLength = httpHeaders.getContentLength();
```