# Why custom header converts to lowercase in android while works fine in IOS on react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios

Why custom header converts to lowercase in android while works fine in IOS on react native! I'm using axios for authentication like this:

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Ul-Id'] = `${Id}`;

What I want to know is:
how to solve it on android, so that it will not be converted to lowercase? 
Why is it working fine on IOS?

Comment: Headers are not meant to be case sensitive https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/5508175

Comment: Not a complete answer but, the server is quite old and it authenticates with caseSensitive header, like I've shown in my question. Any possible alternative?