# How to prevent of converting header name into lower case - Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, header, http-headers

I am developing a `java` based `web application` in `spring-boot` where I am sending `http-header` from `server` to `client` end.

`Server-side` I have used `Spring-boot` in form of `REST API`, whereas `at client` end we have simple plain `HTML5/Angular framework`.

`My query` is, while I am sending any header from server then at client end I always get it into lowercase vs actual.
For example, I am setting header something like,

```
header.add("KK-ACTUAL-VALUE", "sfsfjDFFDHTsdfJKKA");
```

At client end, it gives,

`kk-actual-value` : `"sfsfjDFFDHTsdfJKKA"`; *(Header name converts into lower case!)*

Now, the question is, how to `prevent` it ?

I want to have the same header name what is actually passed by `Server/API`.

Comment: Header names should be case insensitive, does it matter ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive

Comment: As request headers should be, by protocol definition, case insensitive, I don't think it's a good solution to design your app behaviour against it.

Comment: @MatteoBaldi that's right. but there is a specific requirement where I need to implement it.

Comment: @user7294900 I know this is quite odd requirement but this is what I get & need to implement it somehow.

Comment: I am adding custom headers to my response and Spring boot doesn't convert headers to lowercase in my case. Have you checked response headers by making API call from tools like Postman?

Comment: `header.add("KK-ACTUAL-VALUE", "sfsfjDFFDHTsdfJKKA");` - which exact class is header?

Comment: It's a VERY bad idea to have casing in header names, because while header names are technically case-insensitive... they **MUST** be converted to lower-case to be HTTP/2 compliant according to HTTP/2 RFC spec. Any header name that is not lower-cased is considered malformed, so as far as I'm concerned tomcat is doing you a favor here.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like tomcat container turns the headers to lowercase. Since spring boot uses an embedded tomcat is been affected by it. More info here: https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet/issues/65

As the Http standard specifies:

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
> by a colon (":") ...

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

Comment: Header names must be lower-cased before encoding to be HTTP/2 compliant anyway: [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2)

Comment: `Just as in HTTP/1.x, header field names are strings of ASCII
   characters that are compared in a case-insensitive fashion.  However,
   header field names MUST be converted to lowercase prior to their
   encoding in HTTP/2.  A request or response containing uppercase
   header field names MUST be treated as malformed (Section 8.1.2.6).`

Answer (score -2):

To make the header case-sensitive you can set it to the MultiValueMap, and then pass it as a parameter to the HttpHeaders constructor.

The code snippet can be something like this:

```
 MultiValueMap <String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("KK-ACTUAL-VALUE", "sfsfjDFFDHTsdfJKKA");
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders(headers);
```

[image]