# Are HTTP headers space/case/order sensitive?

Tags: http, ssl, http-headers, hsts

Let us assume I have these header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=<expire-time>
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=<expire-time>; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=<expire-time>; preload
```

For purpose of writing regex, I need to know:

Are headers space sensitive? e.g. `max-age=<expire-time> vs. Max-age=<expire-time>`
Are they case-sensitive? e.g. `max-age=   <expire-time> vs. Max-age=<expire-time>`
Are they order-sensitive? e.g. `max-age=<expire-time>; preload vs. preload; max-age=<expire-time>;`

Comment: If you attempt to do this with an regexp, make sure to consider all edge cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for answering this kind of question is the standard - that's what standards are for. To cite from [RFC 7230 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2):

> Each header field consists of a **case-insensitive field name** followed
> by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
> optional trailing whitespace.

As for the field values, this depends on the actual header. For examples in `Set-Cookie` the values are case-sensitive. For `Strict-Transport-Security` you have to look at the relevant standard. In [RFC 6797 it says in section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1):

> 1. The order of appearance of directives is **not significant**.
>    ...
> 2. Directive names are **case-insensitive**.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the relative RFC specifications.

In general [HTTP Header names are case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive) and should not contain white space. [HTTP/2 goes further and states that HTTP Header names should be lower case](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2), and also [white space there causes errors](https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header).

HTTP Header values *can* be case sensitive depending on the header. For the `Strict-Transport-Security` header [your questions are covered in that RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1), specifically:

> It is based on the Generic Grammar defined in [Section 2 of [RFC2616]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2) (which includes a notion of "implied linear whitespace", also known as "implied *LWS").

Which basically means white space is not important.

And then the HSTS RFC goes on to say:

> 1. The order of appearance of directives is not significant.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Directive names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Why "should not" the header names contain white space?