# Is `Content-Disposition` always captialized?

Tags: google-chrome, http, wget, content-disposition

It seems that the standard is that the `Content-Disposition` header name should be capitalized.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266

But I remember that there is some website that does not respect this and use lower case `content-disposition`. Chrome does not have problems of understanding the lower case header. But wget does not recognize it.

Do I misunderstand the standard? Or the header must be in upper cases? Thanks.

Comment: HTTP header **names** are case-insensitive. HTTP header **values** may or may not be case-sensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive)