# Faraday is changing my headers from uppercase to capitalize case

Tags: ruby, hash, faraday

I'm using Faraday to create an SDK that will interact with an API, and I need to send two headers `API_SIGNATURE` and `API_REQUEST_TIME`, so that's what I've created:

```
class APIClient
  def initialize(api_key)
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def get_users
    request.post('/users')
  end

  private

  def request
    Faraday.new(@@BASE_API_URL, headers: headers)
  end

  def headers
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    return {
      API_SIGNATURE: Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@api_key + timestamp),
      API_REQUEST_TIME: timestamp
    }
  end
end
```

And for some reason Faraday is changing API_SIGNATURE to `Api-Signature` and `API_REQUEST_TIME` to `Api-Request-Time`. Is it possible to prevent that from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: HTTP header fields are case-insensitive. It should not matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/823617 Tell the API creators their API is out of spec.

Comment: Agreed. They are working on a new API though.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the keys to strings, but you'll find then that Net::HTTP changes the keys to: `Api_signature` and `Api_request_time`. See here for more info: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/747#issuecomment-439864181

One way you could maybe get around this, though it's a bit hacky, is to create a String class that doesn't lowercase itself like this:

```
class UpperCaseString < String
  def downcase
    self
  end
end
```

Then define your headers like so:

```
  def headers
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    return {
      UpperCaseString.new('API_SIGNATURE') => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@api_key + timestamp),
      UpperCaseString.new('API_REQUEST_TIME') => timestamp
    }
  end
```

Possibly better is to use a different adapter like patron. Add it to your Gemfile then adjust the request to use it:

```
  def request
    Faraday.new(@@BASE_API_URL, headers: headers) do |faraday|
      faraday.adapter :patron
    end
  end
```

In this case you'd still need to make sure your headers are strings not symbols:

```
  def headers
    timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    {
      'API_SIGNATURE' => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@api_key + timestamp),
      'API_REQUEST_TIME' => timestamp
    }
  end
```

Comment: As a note the `return` is not necessary, that value will be returned implicitly if omitted.

Comment: @rainkinz using patron adapter fails with `patron/session.rb:330:in `handle_request': Operation timed out after 1002 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (Faraday::TimeoutError)`. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your @@BASE_API_URL is not something you can get to. Have you tried pinging it or going to the URL using the browser?

Comment: I believe it's because the headers are not changing. I've just inspected them using `puts request.headers`.