# Set axios header with react

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, request, cors

I'm trying to access http://localhost:8080/api/v1/postulant, but I cannot set the access token in the headers. I do the same request on Postman and it works so it's a problem in the Axios request, what did I do wrong?

```js
let headers = {
  Authorization:
    "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjUsImlhdCI6MTYxOTUyNDE4NywiZXhwIjoxNjIwMTI4OTg3fQ.hSXARB-y7rClswYZ380HV5RW77qjYNt5FzW2NfDd8Vw",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/postulant", { headers });
```

on the api I have this code to control the token:

```js
function Auth(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  if (!req.headers["authorization"])
    res.status(400).json({ message: "token invalid" });
}
```

and it gives me that for my console log req.header:
[command prompt result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHtMp.png)

with my postman request, I have this result : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuwhc.png)

so I didn't find the authorization that I provided in the Axios request

Comment: The `Content-Type` is different in both requests -- 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' vs. 'application/json'

Comment: and with postmann both works

Answer (score 0):

Your `{ headers }` looks a bit like destructuring, so that might be the issue. Try

```
const options = {
  headers : {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjUsImlhdCI6MTYxOTUyNDE4NywiZXhwIjoxNjIwMTI4OTg3fQ.hSXARB-y7rClswYZ380HV5RW77qjYNt5FzW2NfDd8Vw',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}
```

And then `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/postulant", options)`

Comment: The syntax they used is correct -- `{ header }` is a shortcut for `{ header: header }`

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the casing of your Authorization.

```
if(!req.headers['Authorization'])
    res.status(400).json({message : 'token invalid'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are case-insensitive as discussed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive). However, the node object key is case-sensitive, so maybe there might be an issue with the brackets in the code itself

So this code

```js
function Auth(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.headers)
}
if(!req.headers['authorization'])
    res.status(400).json({message : 'token invalide'});
}
```

is actually a function that has one instruction which is `console.log(req.headers)`

and then

```js
if(!req.headers['authorization'])
    res.status(400).json({message : 'token invalide'});
}
```

which is not in the function scope so it cannot access the `req.headers` parameter.
Here's how the code should look like:

```js
function Auth(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  if (!req.headers["authorization"]) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "token invalid" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i finally found the solution it was a cors problem.

so i have delete this part of my code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT")
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
next();
});
```

and add this instead

```
const cors= require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: So the issue was in the use of the web framework (I'm guessing Express?), not the request itself? If so, you can tag your question with Express.js or something relevant, so others can find it