# php in IIS - header is not correct

Tags: php, iis, header

I'm testing with my webhook on PHP, run on IIS (windows).
I don't know why i GET with header 'X-ZEvent-Signature', but when receipt is 'X-Zevent-Signature'. In PHP, it is different.
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyaeZ.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PabrZ.png)

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What actual _problem_ do you need to fix? Header names are case-insensitive by definition, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258977/1427878

Comment: @CBroe : 
$headers = getallheaders();
isset($headers["X-ZEvent-Signature"]) = false
isset($headers["X-Zevent-Signature"]) = true

I don't know why header is lowcase 'E'

Comment: You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php to convert all array keys to lowercase first, and then check for `x-zevent-signature`.

Comment: You can try to debug in IDE. Check header array values to see in which step the header change to lowercase automatically.