# Http methods 403 Forbidden for TRACE and OPTIONS

Tags: java, spring

For options and trace request 403 Forbidden response, but for OPTIONS and TRACE request 200 OK in response. Kindly suggest why it is responding in different request with case sensitive.

```
curl -v -X options -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
curl -v -X trace -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
curl -v -X OPTIONS -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
curl -v -X TRACE -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Configure in web.xml file in application made below change but still issue is not resolved. Kindly suggest.

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<http-method>TRACE</http-method>
<http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the requests? They look exactly the same to me, apart from the capitalization of the HTTP method.

Comment: Perhaps reading the [documentation](https://www.mankier.com/1/curl) for `curl -X` will help?

Comment: capitalization of the HTTP method getting different response.                                    curl -v -X TRACE -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  and for other                                                                                                      
 curl -v -X trace -k https://gmtree.nlrdsc/ndcfg/mlibreq.htm
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259048/21105992 <- http method names are case-sensitive